# Formatting Mysql Queries in Table

Tags: php, html

Alright. I have several queries

```
    <?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("mm.hostname.net", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());

$query  = "SELECT card_id,item_bar FROM cards";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "Id :{$row['card_id']} <br>" .
         "Title :($row['title']}" .
         "Description :($row['description']}";
} 

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

My question is how do I get the queries to align in a table like form like below?

```
Id  |  Title  |  Description
============================
1   |  card   |  cute and fluffy
1   |  card   |  cute and fluffy
1   |  card   |  cute and fluffy
1   |  card   |  cute and fluffy
1   |  card   |  cute and fluffy
```

I am pretty new to queries using php (and really still trying to get the hang of them anyway)

Comment: You want proper HTML table, or something along the lines you showed?

Comment: Side note, just to make sure, your query is actually going for 'select card_id, title, description.....' yes?  You have them as being in the result set but not in the actual query.

Comment: @enoyhs , I need it set up like a proper HTML table with the headers at the top, and corresponding data under it.

Comment: Then Parkyprg's answer will help you do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tables:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());

$query  = "SELECT card_id,item_bar FROM cards";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<table>';
echo '<th><td>Id</td><td>Title</td><td>Description</td></th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row['card_id']</td>" .
         "<td>$row['title']</td>" .
         "<td>$row['description']</td></tr>";
} 
echo '</table>';
?>
```